# Haproxy cannot read full URL

Tags: haproxy

I am using 2 types of proxies in my system one is for static files and images, other is for other files.
I want to create a ACL rule for .png .jpeg etc. and route those to my other cheap proxy. My haproxy config looks like this:

```
frontend frnt_proxy_port_40005_dedicated_India_static
bind 0.0.0.0:40005
acl statico path_reg -i \.(jpg|png|gif|js|css|html|ico|woff|eot|ttf|svg|woff2|webp)$
use_backend Static if statico
use_backend bck_proxy_port_40005_dedicated_India_static

backend bck_proxy_port_40005_dedicated_India_static
balance roundrobin
#option forwardfor
#option httpchk
http-check expect status 200
server customer-superproxy.io:241XX customer-superproxy.io:241XX check-send-proxy check inter 5s rise 3 fall 3
```

For testing, I curl this URL:

```
 curl -x 135.xxx.xxx.xxx:40005  https://kinsta.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/jpeg%20file%20format.png
```

I need to read the full URL of a request but in my haproxy config I can only read the domain.
haproxy.log:

```
135.xxx.xxx.xxx:45164 [04/Sep/2023:16:54:37.904] frnt_proxy_port_40005_dedicated_India_static bck_proxy_port_40005_dedicated_India_static/superproxy.io:241XX 0/0/20/22/1285 200 12903 - - CD-- 611/1/0/0/0 0/0 "CONNECT kinsta.com:443 HTTP/1.1"
```

as you can see ì am not able to see full URL. How can I see the whole URL and create ACL rule based on this?